# I keep on getting strange notifications on my phone from my Gmail account (Calendar). Is it a virus?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, google-account

[image]This is the second time I get this strange notification on my phone.
In the notification panel I see a "calendar event notification" (from google) with a strange title, something...hot...
Example "Tonight at 9pm party...." and then below another notification as if in the calendar there were that event written.
I NEVER came across these notifications and it's 5 years I've been  using this account.
What's happening?

Comment: This is what is happening to me - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/google-calendar-has-events-that-i-didnt-create-and-its-not-shared

Long story short, Google creates events in my calendar that I didn't ever actually create. They're "invitations".....to parties, etc.....

Answer (score 0):

It could be because someone has gotten hold of your account. It is probably a good idea to visit [myaccount.google.com/device-activity](http://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) and check if there are any unknown devices.

If you're not sure, it is best to just change your password which will force all signed-in devices to sign out.

Answer (score 0):

This could be something that Google added to your calendar due to an email received on Gmail.

From [Events from Gmail](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084018?hl=en)

> When you get an email about an event like a flight, concert, or
>   restaurant reservation, it's added to your calendar automatically. If
>   you don't want events from Gmail on your calendar, you can delete a
>   single event, or change your settings so that events aren't added
>   automatically.

One solution is to disable this feature. From the same source as the above quote

> ### Stop adding events from Gmail automatically
>
> When you turn off the setting to add events from Gmail, all past
>   events added from Gmail will be removed from your calendar. If you
>   turn this setting back on, only events in the future will be added.
>
> 1. Open Google Calendar.
> 2. In the top right, click Settings Settings and then Settings.
> 3. Next to "Events from Gmail," uncheck the box next to "Add automatically."
> 4. At the bottom of the page, click Save.